# Does a typical mobile adapter draw current when no load is attached?

Tags: power, adapter

**Summary:**
I am comparing the trade off of wasting my time daily plugging and unplugging multiple chargers at multiple sockets.  I need to know **approximately** how much **Amp** is my adapter drawing every second when in no load (have not attached my mobile/tablet).  Will it be mostly **0**? On in the ballpark of **<10 mA, <50mA, <100mA**?

**Charger specs :** (AK717)
OP: DC 5v 2amp branded
IP: AC 240V .3A

Comment: Yes - it will probably draw some small amount of current depending on the technology.  You will need to measure the quiescent current when the charger is in standby mode.  There are plug in adapters that will make this measurement for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will draw current. It will also consume energy (what you pay for on your electric bill).

Modern mobile chargers consume perhaps 0.01kWh/day according to [this book](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/sustainable/book/tex/cft.pdf).(see page 68 in the book, not PDF, numbering) - **measurements below indicate that contemporary chargers tend to do 2-5x better that that**..

That's not a lot- you can calculate what it costs and/or what percentage of your total energy usage it is. At $0.10/kWh, 0.005kWh/day represents about 20 cents a year. If it takes you 5 seconds per day to plug and unplug, you're receiving an after-tax ROI of 40 cents an hour for your time.

The current draw may be rather higher than the energy consumption would imply because some of the current is reactive.. however it cannot be less.

Here's an excerpt from a set of actual measurements, made by [Ken Shirriff](http://www.righto.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html):

[image]

As you can see, the ones made by responsible manufacturers are generally 200mW or less, which would imply a current draw of a mA or two (maybe 1/10 of that) depending on reactive power, and depending on whether it was connected to a 120VAC or 230VAC mains.

As [Professor MacKay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_J._C._MacKay) concludes, I would say it's a waste of time to unplug a modern mobile charger for a person living normally in a developed country. There are far bigger energy fish to fry.

Answer (score 1):

European guidelines specify that standby mode without a display should be less than 0.5W.

For a simple charger I can see it being less, but 0.5W is a good ballpark.

That makes a current of around 2mA for EU mains, or double that for US mains.

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=GFFLVJuFHsHN7Qbq-oHYAg&url=http://ec.europa.eu/energy/efficiency/ecodesign/doc/legislation/guidelines_for_smes_1275_2008_okt_09.pdf&ved=0CBwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNG4HYGJlRnJl3TNoG2mhkK-2QVmJg&sig2=tU-CLHm_AjOY0DKLSX_2Tg